# jQuery Delay Not Working, CSS is though

Tags: jquery

I've run into a problem that I cannot figure out:

```
$(doc).ready(function(){
    $("span").html("<span>No</span>");

    $("button").click(function(){
        $("span").html(getRandomInt(50, 200));
        $(this).fadeOut(500);
        $("#title").delay(501).css({'margin-bottom': '110'});
    });
});




var doc = document;

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()) * 259;

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Why does the `.delay(501)` in the `$("#title")` not work?  the `.css()` works, just not the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `.css()` function does not work based on a queue, it is a synchronous operation....

Looks like you are trying to set the margin property after the button is faded out, so use the complete callback method provided by jQuery

```
$("button").fadeOut(500, function(){
    $("#title").css({'margin-bottom': '110'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, worked great.  I'll be sure you vote best answer when I can.